LightGallery moves image to top left corner when I zooming in, how to fix?
I have a problem with LightGallery in wordpress. I have included all libraries to the head like this
if(is_page_template('template-home.php') || is_tax() || is_search() || is_page_template('template-refferences.php') || is_page_template('template-gallery.php') ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('light_gallery_css', get_template_directory_uri()."/includes/lightgallery/css/lightgallery.min.css", array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'light_gallery_js',   get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/lightgallery/js/lightgallery.min.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    if(is_page_template('template-home.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'light_gallery_js_1', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/lightgallery/js/lg-video.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'light_gallery_js_2', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/lightgallery/js/lg-autoplay.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'light_gallery_js_3', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/lightgallery/js/lg-zoom.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'light_gallery_js_4', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/lightgallery/js/lg-thumbnail.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'light_gallery_js_5', get_template_directory_uri().'/includes/lightgallery/js/lg-fullscreen.js', array(), '1.0', true );
}

And I have made a gallery on my page and added option to open lightgallery and swipe images, that works fine, but when I click on zoom in icon it just moves images to top left corner until it disappear... It won't zoom image.
I don't have so many plugins that can make conflict there and it's custom made template, I have used lightgallery on websites but this is the first time that I see the error and can't find the solution what else to try.
this is my JS code for clicking button to open gallery.
$('.l_b_btn').on('click', function() {
            var dynamic = $(this).data('dynamic');
            console.log(dynamic);
            if(dynamic.length){
                $(this).lightGallery({
                    dynamic: true,
                    dynamicEl: dynamic,
                    zoom: true,
                    animateThumb: false,
                    zoomFromOrigin: true,
                    allowMediaOverlap: true,
                    toggleThumb: true,
                });
            }
            else{
                $(this).lightGallery({
                    // exThumbImage: 'data-exthumbimage',
                    // thumbnail: false
                });
            }
        });

and below is image to show what happens when I click on zoom icon

Please help.
Thanks in advance.
